How to get custom taxonomy from Custom Post Type to display in Post Block in Unlimited Elements
I have a custom post type called merit_badge and a custom taxonomy called counselor.  I am trying to get it into a Post Block on Unlimited Elements.  This is what I have so far and I'm using CPT UI to create the custom taxonomy and custom post.
{% if show_counselor == "true" %}<div class="ue-grid-item-category">{% for term in item.post_lists.terms %}{{term.name|raw}}{% endfor %}</div>{% endif %}


Aren't Unlimited Elements and CPT UI third party plugins?  Your best bet would be to ask their developers for assistance as each plugin has it's own nuances.
